# Subtracting two values in SQL Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, difference

I need to subtract two values I am calculating on the fly in a case statement but I cant seem to get it done. Here is what I am trying to do  and the error I get is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword END':

```
[Date] = 
  CASE 
    WHEN [col] = 'YES' 
    THEN CONCAT(MONTH(AnniversaryDate),'/',DAY(AnniversaryDate),'/',(YEAR(GETDATE()) + (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(AnniversaryDate)))
    END,
```

Should I instead store the difference in some other column rather than calculate the subtraction where I am currently calculating it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: well I feel like an idiot. I counted them about 3 times but just didn't see it :(. Thank you! and Happy Holidays!

Comment: And to you as well!  And don't feel bad about the counting; take a look at the edit history to find my first answer.  :-)